# PowerShell script to search and replace text

Tags: powershell

Hello I have a script that searches for a matching string, then replace it

I want to replace all occurrence of "6.0.0.0.2010 Wave Embedded 6.0 (2010)" with "6.0.0.0.XXXX Wave Embedded 6.0 (XXXX)"

I want to match strings that match exactly that, however if i modify the 6.0.0.0.XXXX then it deletes everything after that..

my script :

```
(Get-Content C:\Users\gadmin\Desktop\temp\test.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '6.0.0.0.*$', '6.0.0.0.XXXX' } | Set-Content C:\Users\gadmin\Desktop\temp\test1.txt
```

Comment: Worked for me without the space after the $ in the replace. `"Embedded 6.0 (2010)" | % { $_ -replace "^Embedded 6.0.*$", "Embedded 6.0 (XXXX)" }`

Comment: I needed to modify my question, it wasn't exactly accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had no problem with my teststring, is the occurence always the same?

```
"6.0.0.0.2010 Wave Embedded 6.0 (2010)"| ForEach {
    $_ -replace '6.0.0.0.2010 Wave Embedded 6.0 (2010)', 
                '6.0.0.0.XXXX Wave Embedded 6.0 (XXXX)'}
```

So this should work also (you may insert a new line after a pipe or opening curly bracket):

```
$FileIn = "C:\Users\gadmin\Desktop\temp\test.txt"
$FileOut= "C:\Users\gadmin\Desktop\temp\test1.txt"

[RegEx]$Search = '6.0.0.0.\d{4} Wave Embedded 6.0 \(\d{4}\)'
Get-Content $FileIn -Raw| ForEach {
        $_ -replace $Search, '6.0.0.0.XXXX Wave Embedded 6.0 (XXXX)'}|
Set-Content $FileOut
```

Comment: ahhh i wasn't clear in my question the 2010 in the string is the variable and will not be the same. However, i just copied and paste your solution and it did not modify, if anything it should replace that line...i wonder where i went wrong

Comment: So what are you searching for? Four digits will be represented by `\d{4}`

Comment: another thing since there are mutiple entries of 6.0.0.0 in my text file, how do i constrained  this match '6.0.0.0.\d{4}' to have to be followed by 'Wave Embedded'

Comment: There was still a flaw, the parentheses in the search have to be escaped because they have a special meaning in a RegEx (capture group). I edited my script, It should work now.